# MS Edge/Selenium Options

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently was asked to redo some Selenium work using MS Edge.

Googling around and checking various MSDN pages, have not been able to find a list of command line switches.

What I'm looking for is any equivalent to a `ChromeOptions().addOptions("--disable-notifications")`, but would also like to know what other options are exposed for startup options.

Can anyone point me towards a way to get that information?

Tried using `getCapabilityNames()` on a new EdgeOptions object and then `.toArray()`-ing my variable, which just returns a character Array of 'browserName', which happens to just be a String field in my class.

Any pointers/help appreciated.

Comment: providing an URL via commandline is possible; it looks like that all other command line switches are user voices which are still unheard https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9245247-inprivate-command-line-switch

Comment: @StefanPrugg thanks for the heads up

Comment: I'm only seeing "browserName" return from getCapabilityNames().

Comment: @pcalkins thanks good to know. Guess it was just coincidence my class field shared the same name

Comment: it looks like .setPageLoadStrategy might be implemented (takes a string), but .setUnhandledPromptBehaviour is not... which would be useful for notifications.  Since it's part of the webdriver spec I assume it is coming.

Comment: yea I saw setPageLoadStrategy, but it just has 4 options - Default, Eager, None, and Normal: https://www.fuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/3.11.1/lib/net45/WebDriver.dll/OpenQA.Selenium.Edge/EdgePageLoadStrategy

From the namespace doesn't look like passing in command line args into options offers much at the moment

Comment: This list seems to be updated with a column for status and available release:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver

Comment: @pcalkins perfect, this is something to work from, big thanks!